# Schemacrawler is not fetching the data from oracle

Tags: schemacrawler

I tried to fetch Mysql table details as below, it is fetching all the table detail but it is not fetching any data from oracle using below sc commands. Is it required any additional configuration for oracle.

> MySql sc -driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>   -url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/doctool -user=root -password=password -schemas=doctool -infolevel=standard -command=list
>
> Oracle sc -driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
>   -url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl -user=certus2713 -password=certus2713 -schemas=certus2713 -infolevel=standard -command=list

Answer (score 0):

Venkatesan,

The Oracle driver and database may be case-sensitive. Please try `-schemas=CERTUS2713` Or, you can try to drop the `-schemas` altogether.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)